# Define parameters type on variable of type Function

Tags: typescript

I have a variable that which is type is `Function`. Then, I initialize this function as a function with two string parameters:

```
let aux2: Function = (draftId: string, mode: string) => {...}
```

I want to know if I can tell to the `let aux2: Function` variable only can be instanciated with `Function`s that has two string parameters, something like this:

```
let aux2: Function<string, string> = (draftId: string, mode: string) => {...}
```

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank I did not understand your question. Can you please elaborate more so I could understand better?

Comment: The duplicate talks about parameters but the idea is the same.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir  yes. it is not really duplicate, but redirects the readers to the the base problem of this question.